# What does NSLog actually do?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nslog

I am having a weird problem. I am using a method from Apple's private frameworks in my application. When I call it for the first time, it works. When I call it for the second time immediately without anything in between, it crashes. However, if I put NSLog between the two calls, it works wonderfully. So I try removing NSLog and puting for-loops, sleep(), printf("..."), and fprintf(stderr, "...") between them to emulate NSLog, but it doesn't help. I am wondering how the method knows that I use NSLog? In other words, what does NSLog actually do to affect the behaviors of the method?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT:**

I seem to solve this problem. I will share my solution here and hope it may be useful to some people.

I am creating a multitouch-related application using MultitouchSupport.framework. I copied code from http://aladino.dmi.unict.it/?a=multitouch and added a `CFRelease` at the end of the loop. So, basically, my main method looks like this :

```
int main(void) { 
    int i; 
    NSMutableArray* deviceList = (NSMutableArray*)MTDeviceCreateList(); //grab our device list 
    for(i = 0; i<[deviceList count]; i++) { //iterate available devices 
        MTRegisterContactFrameCallback([deviceList objectAtIndex:i], touchCallback); //assign callback for device 
        MTDeviceStart([deviceList objectAtIndex:i], 0); //start sending events 
    }
    CFRelease((CFMutableArrayRef)deviceList); 
    printf("Ctrl-C to abort\n"); 
    sleep(-1); 
    return 0; 
}
```

After running for a while, it will show "Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”."
And here is the stack trace:

```
#0 0x7fff8795496e in ParsedMultitouchFrameRepInitialize
#1 0x7fff879565b1 in mt_HandleMultitouchFrame
#2 0x7fff87955a03 in mt_DequeueDataFromDriver
#3 0x7fff87955b29 in mt_DequeueMultitouchDataFromDriverThreadEntry
#4 0x7fff831b3456 in _pthread_start
#5 0x7fff831b3309 in thread_start
```

However, if I put NSLog below MTDeviceStart, it will not crash.

The reason I added `CFRelease((CFMutableArrayRef)deviceList)` to the original code is that I think objects that are created from functions named *Create* or *Copy* should be released by ourselves. But it turns out that if I remove it like the original code does, it will not crash, even without using NSLog.

So, maybe it's because I release `deviceList` too early? But if that's so, why does NSLog seem to be able to prevent the crash?

Comment: Its probably has nothing to do with the NSLog. I would post some code.

Comment: Please edit both the code and the stack trace into your question.

Comment: You're correct about the naming convention, but since `MTDeviceCreateList` is a private function, it might be violating/not conforming to it. (Perhaps it means “create the devices array that is intended to remain alive for the duration of the process, and return the pointer to it”.) Try running your program (with crash) under Instruments's Zombies instrument. With that, you should be able to prove whether your release is an over-release, or otherwise determine the true cause of the crash.

Comment: I'd guess that the `MT` functions don't retain the objects you pass to them, so they die too early if you release the device list.

Comment: The "Create" rule is a Carbon rule, not a Cocoa one. Only functions with "alloc", "new" and "copy" pass ownership to the caller in Cocoa.

Comment: Tom Dalling: But if `MTDeviceCreateList` is a function, it's not too unreasonable to expect it to conform to the Core Foundation (not Carbon) rules rather than the Cocoa rules; just don't be too surprised when it doesn't, because it's a private function and private functions don't have to conform to any of the public-API rules. (In other words, Apple only promises that public APIs work certain ways; they promise nothing about private interfaces.) It doesn't matter whether ifvc is using Cocoa or not.

Comment: In the 'early' days of iPhone OS 3, I read a book by an guy who learnt to code for iPhone before the SDK (can't remember his name; O'Reilly book). He mentioned what a senseless mess the private APIs are, and how orderly and elegant (if limited, at least then) the public ones were in contrast. Wonder if it's still true, or Apple 'cleaned the house' a bit; never done any jb/private API yet.

Answer (score 2):

Something similar to this:

```
static inline void NSLogMessageString(NSString *string){
  NSString *date=[[NSDate date]
   descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%F"
                        timeZone:nil locale:nil];
  NSString *process=[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processName];

  NSLogFormat(@"%@ %@[%d:%lx] %@",date,process,NSPlatformProcessID(),NSPlatformThreadID(),string);
}

void NSLogv(NSString *format,va_list arguments) {
  NSString *string=NSStringNewWithFormat(format,nil,arguments,NULL);

  NSLogMessageString(string);

 [string release];
}

void NSLog(NSString *format,...) {
  va_list arguments;

  va_start(arguments,format);

  NSLogv(format,arguments);
}
```

Thanks for asking this question lol, I wanted to rewrite it so I could add debugging variables, meaning I could turn all NSLogging calls off when needed..

Answer (score 1):

It takes a long time. I'm not sure why. It prints the date/time, process name, process ID, thread ID, and (finally) the string you asked for. I *think* it also sends the log message to syslogd (either Xcode or iPCU's console shows multiline NSLogs as a single entry; I forget which); the IPC there might be significant.

Try using syslog() (`#import <syslog.h>` and then `syslog(LOG_INFO, "Hello there!");`, if it works but you get no output, try changing the priority (see `man 3 syslog`).

Comment: Yes, NSLog sends the message to ASL, the same as syslog does. I'm not sure what you expect syslog to do differently—just not print it to stderr?

Comment: I was responding to "if I put NSLog between the two calls, it works", suggesting that syslog() might do some of the things that NSLog does to make it "work".

Answer (score 1):

NSLog can affect issues like the one you are running into because it affects the order that threads execute because when you call NSLog in a background thread, it has to gain exclusive access to stdout. printf debugging tricky problems with threads often leads to "heisenbugs" for this reason (i.e. they change behavior when you try to examine them).

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with memory management: an extraneous release perhaps.  If you post the traceback, it might be some help in tracking down the issue. (As it turns out, someone on Twitter I follow mentioned something like this last night).

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. I tried removing a CFRelease from my code, and it now works perfectly. I'm not sure why though. I have just added my code into my question.

Comment: Be careful: if it was being released too early, but needed to be ultimately released anyway, it means that now it isn't crashing but leaking instead (i.e., if it was a problem of timing and you had the retain counts right from the beginning)